# How to get domain user name from Outlook 2003?

Tags: c#, vsto, .net-2.0, outlook-2003

I have done an AddIn for Outlook 2003 with VSTO 2005. I have a small problem. The users log into windows with a local account. However, in Outlook, they get an extra login form where they need to input their domain account in order to use Outlook with their data.

What I need to do is get the name with which the user logs into Outlook. So far, I tested Environment.UserName and Environment.UserDomainName, but the first one returns the local account name and the second one just the domain name.

Does anybody have any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Start with `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.Accounts.Item(1).CurrentUser.AddressEntry`.  The best you're going to get out of that, since it's not tied directly to a domain user -- rather, it's tied to a mailbox/account -- is the user's display name and either SMTP or MS Exchange email address.  From there, you can interrogate Active Directory using the classes provided in the .NET `System.DirectoryServices` namespace to look up the domain account associated with the mailbox.  I have the code, but it's in VB.NET, not C#.

Comment: @LeonidasFett, can you confirm the value of `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.Accounts.Item(1).CurrentUser.AddressEn‌​try` .  I can help you with the AD query, which is going to be a bit tricky if you AD denies anonymous queries since you aren't running locally as a domain user.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply but I have been kinda busy. Anyway it turned out that I needed to get the username from an Exchange Server and for that I would have had to use C++ to access the username from there. Or at least so I have been told. Anyway I found another way which didn't involve the ES or AD.